# Calling FQL Method to query facebook

Tags: silverlight, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the Facebook C# SDK V4.2.1 to creat a simple application in silverlight 4, i wanto to get the profile picture. for what i know is that the best way is to cal the FQL method, but i'm new to this and i don´t know how to call FQL method.

i've searched the net and not found anything
If you can help me, I would apreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need FQL you could simply get the real picture URL (and not the redirect) from

http://graph.facebook.com/{uid}?fields=picture

This will return a JSON object which includes the picture field

Answer (score 0):

Facebook profile pictures are publically availible. You can see picture at url http://graph.facebook.com/username/picture
For example, my profile picture: http://graph.facebook.com/pavel.surmenok/picture
And large one: http://graph.facebook.com/pavel.surmenok/picture?type=large

Comment: but this is not the real link to the picture, gives a HTTP 302 (temporary redirect) to a second URL, that is way in silverlight i can´t get the image, if i use string urlString = "http://graph.facebook.com/{uid}/picture?type=large"; image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(urlString , UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); This will not work

Comment: for what i can understand the FQL method can be use in a asp application like this

fbApp = new FacebookApp(); FacebookAppExtensions.Query(fbApp,QueryString);

but this method is not available in a Silverlight application

Comment: They are only publicly available if the user uses default privacy settings.  It is possible to lock it down so the photo is not publicly available